# FacebookConnect integration with ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, webforms, facebook

I'm working on a site with a Facebook Connect integration on blog posts. I want a Facebook .NET SDK that will **allow me to**:

1. Authenticate that a user is logged into FB. The actual login will be done via the typical FBML login button and simple JS with the XD Receiver.
2. Be able to push data from my WebForm to the user's FB profile, such as a status update.

I **do not need to**:

1. Create an actual FB application that goes on your profile, like "Cheer for the Red Sox" app or whatever. I do completely understand that I need to create an app using the Developer application but I'm not indenting to create a real full app.
2. Do any special stuff other than know the user's basics and push data to the profile.

Now are there any good starting points or SDKs I should look at. I've tried Facebook.NET and also peeked into FBConnectAuth. It seems like the former is too much and the latter is too little of what I need. However, that was a quick glance so are there any people with good experiences that did simple things?

Help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried this example?

[Post status to Facebook profile without Facebook modal window using ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1638279/post-status-to-facebook-profile-without-facebook-modal-window-using-asp-net)

If you have any feature requests for FBConnectAuth, please let me know.

Adam

Answer (score 0):

For me, [**Raya**](http://raya.codeplex.com/)'s integration of Facebook Connect is the best example out there. The author also has a good [blog post](http://my6solutions.com/post/2009/04/05/Integration-of-Facebook-Connect-on-ASP-NET-MVC.aspx) where he describes how he integrated it with his existing web application..

Comment: Thanks for the info. It seems Raya is for ASP.NET MVC which I'm not using. I'm just using ASP.NET with WebForms